# Where is the Send button?

Tags: mac, email, ventura

I'm running Ventura 13.3.1 on a 2021-22 MacBook Pro, and ever since the upgrade, I've had to resort to using the keyboard command to send mail. Not a huge issue, but lots of users seem to be having this problem.
I've tried adding it from the "Customize Toolbar" dialog box, and it isn't in there either.
Any answers?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with a screen shot of the missing element?   It will help in identifying the issue.

Comment: When you have a *message window* open and select `View > Customize Toolbar...` do you not see the "Send Message" (paper airplane) icon as an available option? On My Mac (macOS 13.3.1 (a)) it is there is the left upper corner of that dialog... But you **have** to be in an email message window to make that change...